# How to combine Angular and Rails 4 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a navbar. On this navbar are four links. Three of them are angular links that look like this:

```
<a href="#/"><span><%= t "navbar.mystream" %></span></a>
<a href="#teach/"><span><%= t "navbar.mystream" %></span></a>
<a href="#discover/"><span><%= t "navbar.mystream" %></span></a>
```

One is a rails link that deals with user accounts and so I want to keep it outside the scope of my angular app for the time being. It looks like this:

```
<%= link_to edit_user_registration_path do %>
  <span><%= t "navbar.account" %></span>
<% end %>
```

The links work fine until I go to the rails path which takes me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/edit
```

Now if I click one of the angular links it just adds the '#' to the url rather than removing the '`users/edit` part and adding the # as it does otherwise.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, I'm sure you can see, is that without Angular loaded on your account page, its routing can't catch the hashed `#path` changes. If your URL structure remains simple, you can probably get past that by rendering the full URL (including hash pieces) in the header. That is,

```
http://localhost:3000/#
http://localhost:3000/#teach
...
http://localhost:3000/users/edit
```

On your Angular pages, the only part that changes is the hash, and browsers usually won't refresh the page when that happens. Moving between Angular pages and your user account is a real path change that the browser will notice and refresh.

If that doesn't work out, or if your URLs get more complicated, you might need to render different headers depending on the page. Eg, only hashes in the Angular header and full paths in the non-Angular header. That's bound to get fiddly and irritating as your backend learns more about the frontend and becomes entangled with it.

The opposite approach is to just run Angular on every page. You can still do your account editing without it (typical form submissions, etc.), but loading your Angular app alongside should allow the router to catch links the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and full explanation. This all makes sense now.